# Looking for a reference use of PoseWithCovariance: any pkg using it?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

[PoseWithCovariance](http://www.ros.org/doc/unstable/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovariance.html) has a 6x6 covariance matrix which, according to [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#covariance-representation), corresponds to these variables in this order: (x, y, z, rotation about X axis, rotation about Y axis, rotation about Z axis). With rotation around fixed axes, not like in the "common" yaw/pitch/roll various conventions.

I'm working in a pkg for covariance transformations ([pose_cov_ops](http://ros.org/wiki/pose_cov_ops)) so it would be great if I could **compare my numerical results with any other existing ROS packages** that output PoseWithCovariance at present. Checks would go in the package unit tests.

**More explicitly:** I'm looking for some "stable" ROS package which computes covariances in 6D, so I can peek its source code and make sure I'm following the right convention.

Any recommendation?

If there're none, I'll assume the 3x3 rotation matrix is as follows:

<strike>R = R_x(roll) * R_y(pitch) * R_z(yaw)</strike>

R = R_z(yaw) * R_y(pitch) * R_x(roll)

where matrices are in the <strike>inverse</strike> same order than the non-global axis, yaw-pitch-roll convention.

PS: wouldn't it have made more sense to keep a 7x7 covariance for the unit quaternion form? In general, equations for uncertainty propagation in this form are far simpler than for Euler angles. Is there room for a PoseWith7x7CovarianceStamped yet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30919/looking-for-a-reference-use-of-posewithcovariance:-any-pkg-using-it?/) by [Jose Luis Blanco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2046/jose-luis-blanco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 288 on 2012-03-30

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Blanco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2046/jose-luis-blanco/) on 2012-04-11**:
Just for the records: the numerical values of yaw/pitch/roll in the dynamic-axes (rotating) convention are exactly the same than those in the roll/pitch/yaw fixed-axes convention. So a conversion of covariance matrices between both formats becomes just a permutation. Hope it may help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK there is no ROS package which make the transform between two poses with uncertainty (perhaps http://ros.org/wiki/bfl but I don't think so). Because of this the package pose_cov_ops seems unique. I belive that the MRPT ([[mrpt-ros-pkg]]) in which the pose_cov_ops package is based looks very powerful handling poses with uncertainty and ROS should take advantage of this fact.

I think that this package should be integrated in the generic http://ros.org/wiki/tf2 package as a plugin in a similar way that the kdl package was integrated (see https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/experimental/file/40be50217595/tf2_geometry_msgs/include/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h). Perhaps the tf2 package should be refactored to support more explicitly the inverse tranformation or at least the unary inverse transform.

**Edit:**
Definitely I think you can find what you are looking for in the source code of the package http://ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is  [tf_uncertainty](http://ros.org/wiki/uncertain_tf) that might do what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-06-26**:
I don't locate in the package source code the gaussian error propagation (using Jacobians) produced by the nonlinear tranforms. The resulting uncertainty after a transform is represented by a pose cloud(particles) and not as a PoseWithCovariance. In such case it is not what José Luis is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

uncertain_tf is an extension to tf that allows to maintain uncertainty in the translation and rotation of **coordinate frames.**

if you want to add uncertainity to your odometry data in 6D you should check out robot_pose_ekf

turtlebot and pr2 use uncertainity for their odom datas
check out this example of turtlebot

https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/e47d5a1dca1c/turtlebot_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py

here is another example from cwru robotics' package

https://github.com/cwru-robotics/cwru-ros-pkg/blob/master/cwru_semi_stable/cwru_base/src/odom_translator.py

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1